# Location of EntityFramework T4 templates

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, t4, ef-model-first

When you do database-first or model-first (EDMX) in EntityFramework, I believe Visual Studio generates code off T4 templates, I would like to create a new out of the default and throw some customization in but I can't find their location anywhere.

Comment: does this article help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010, do not use T4 to generate the model's codebehind, it uses the `EntityModelCodeGenerator` tool.

Since `EntityModelCodeGenerator` tool cannot be modified, Microsoft provided the ability to create an `ADO.NET EntityObject Generator` which will generate a T4 base template which is equivalent to what the `EntityModelCodeGenerator` generates.

Answer (score 1):

Expand the .edmx file in the VS Solution explorer to access and edit directly. To make backup copies, when browsing with windows explorer you should find them in the same project folder or other folder you placed your .edmx file in.

[image]

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention I was in using VS2010. I changed the tagging :)